# Resize Calendar in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar, resize

I found a lot of similar questions on internet but no solutions to solve my problem.
The problem is really simple, I just want to resize a calendar, nothing more. Many people recommanded to use a Viewbox like that :

```
<Viewbox
    Width="400"
    Height="400"
    Stretch="Fill"
    StretchDirection="Both">
    <Calendar />
</Viewbox>
```

This solution seems to work for many guys that faced the same issue, but didn't work for me as you can see on the snapshot below :

[result of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi02x.png)

I have tried other values for StrechDirection but nothing is getting better.

The ViewBox is inside a simple UserControl.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you're going to have to post the code for `Calendar.Base`.

Comment: Oops sorry, I forgot to delete it. I have tried some changes within the style but this is obsolete now, I will edit the post.

Comment: Copying just that exact cope into a project gives me a uniformly scaled calandar, not a skewed one like in the picture. There must be something else.

Comment: I've got no issue on a new project as well. But in my Prism project, I've got this issue. I've asked Brian Lagunas (Prism creator) and he told me that Prism doesn't influence the UI... I will keep searching

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I have changed my buttons style for the whole application. Because a calendar contains a lot of buttons, each button in the calendar were impacted by my buttons style.